# Odd program behavior with fgets() and initialized variables

Tags: c, fgets

Please consider the following program code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *cmd;
    int exitCommand = 1;
    int validCommands = 0;
    int commandValid = 0;

    while(exitCommand != 0)
    {
        printf("> ");
        fgets(cmd, 101, stdin);
        if(*cmd != '\n')
        {
            printf("%s\n", cmd);
        }
        exitCommand = strncmp("exit", cmd, 4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling this program in Windows 10 x64 cmd via `gcc -o cmmd cmmd.c` and then running via `cmmd`
The program seems to terminate unexpectedly without printing the output.
However, if I remove at least one of the variables except `exitCommand`, or don't initialize the variables except for `exitCommand`, the program behaves properly.
I am confused as to what is causing this problem. Stack memory shouldn't be a problem since all this occupies less than 1000000B.
I suspect `fgets()` could be causing this, but there are no run-time errors that I am able to refer to. Should I perhaps have allocated explicit space for `cmd` char array? The compiler being used is **TDM-GCC**. Kindly explain the phenomenon.

Comment: `cmd` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: `cmd` needs to be an actual array, not an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Can you turn up warning level in your compiler? You are using `cmd` uninitialized and any recent compiler should complain about that. Using a random memory address to store your input is not a good idea. Either use `malloc` to reserve some memory or make `cmd` an array.

Comment: hi, what compiler directive can i use to increase the warning level? does ```-Werror``` work?

Comment: @mindoverflow You can use `-Wall` `-Wextra` `-pedantic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char* cmd` is uninitialized. To be able to store the input, you have to make `cmd` point to the adress of a valid array :

```
char cmd[100];
fgets(cmd, 100, stdin);
// here you can use cmd as a null terminated string
```

Also you should check for `fgets` return value to detect any error.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to rectify the issue via ```char *cmd = malloc(101);``` and the program now works as expected.

Comment: Remember to `free(cmd)` after using it, or it will result in memory leaks. (That is why dynamic memory allocation is avoided when not needed : here you know the size of your array at compile time, so you don't need a malloc, you can allocate your array on the stack)

Comment: thank you for the reminder, it's vital, but very easy to forget.